# Execute command as admin using subprocess

Tags: python, windows

I want to execute installation command as an admin via subprocess.
How can I run command as an admin? Here what I have so far:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('cd C:\\Users\\user\\', shell=True)
subprocess.call(
    'runas /user:Administrator | echo Y| choco install dropbox', shell=True
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import os
subprocess
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\user\\")

cmd= subprocess.Popen(["runas", "/noprofile", "/user:Administrator", "|", "echo", "Y", "|", "choco", "install", "dropbox"],stdin=sp.PIPE)
cmd.stdin.write('password')
cmd.communicate()
```

Comment: I have an error: cmd.stdin.writelines('password')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: can you try: 'password'.encode() or 'password'.encode(''utf-8'')?

Comment: or you can skip "cmd.stdin.write('password')"

Comment: i tried, but now it does executes the command, just showing that command is done without any errors, but it should actually install dropbox via console

Comment: try prefixing letter `b` to your string to make it byte like. Like so `cmd.stdin.write(b'password')`

Comment: The "Administrator" account is disabled by default and should be disabled on end-user systems, so no code that needs to be generally reliable should depend on being able to use this account. Thus no software that needs generally reliable administrator access, such as to install software or services, can use runas.exe, since this application cannot elevate via UAC. A program that needs to spawn a child process with admin access must use the "runas" operation with `ShellExecute[Ex]W`, or use a system service that has the right to spawn an admin process in an interactive session.